# malloc didn't return NULL but indexing array give Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management, segmentation-fault, malloc

i am using codeblocks, my code is as following :

allocating the array T :

```
long long TAILLE_MAX= 5000000000000;
long long *T= malloc(sizeof(long long)*TAILLE_MAX);
```

then i want to use a part of the array each time and fill it with descending values :

```
long long step= 5;
for(long long TAILLE=500000000; TAILLE<=TAILLE_MAX; TAILLE*=step){
    if(step==2) step=5;
    else step= 2;

    for(long long n=0; n<TAILLE; n++) T[n]= TAILLE-n;
    // rest of code (which is not reached) ...
```

the problem is in this loop :

```
for(long long n=0; n<TAILLE; n++) T[n]= TAILLE-n;
```

it gives Segmentation fault, and when i used the debugger to analyse the problem i found that it gives the error every time when n reach `121197052` which must be included in the array,

i thought that it is a problem with the heap size, but the T is allocated by `malloc` and it didn't return NULL,

i tried to increase the size of the heap by adding this to the linker : `-Wl,--stack,568435456`
, but same error,

what it is strange is that i tried to allocate a less than `5000000000000` but `malloc` return NULL !!!! how it can allocate a big size and returns NULL for less size !

i have windows 7 Ultimate 64bit, 4Gb of memory, Intel Core Duo 2.80GHz.

thanks in advance for any suggestion.

EDIT:
about holding the question : i am not searching for debugging the program! not at all! i am asking about the behavior of various instruction in it like `malloc` , memory allocation ..., i don't need a solution for my program i am searching for useful informations about the above points which can be useful for other members, even the title shows that i am asking about the behavior of something.

Comment: That's an obscene amount of memory

Comment: Is the compiler 64bit too? My MSVC 15.0 is 32 bit even though 64 bit machine. What is maximum value you can pass to `malloc`? I suspect your `long long` is being truncated.

Comment: Does your compiler which you use via codeblock IDE create 64bit output? Malloc takes size_t as size parameter. On a 32bit system your requested size of 40,000,000,000,000 bytes is far beyond 32bit limits.

Comment: `printf("%zu", (size_t)(sizeof(long long) * TAILLE_MAX));`

Comment: So the reason for this error is that you either did not turn on warnings, or you ignored them. See the comments to Weather Vane's answer!

Comment: What does `printf("%d\n", (int) sizeof (size_t));` print?  This result is central to your code issue.

Comment: yes exactly @WeatherVane remind me to check it, it gives 4 which mean that `long long int` will be truncated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`malloc` takes a `size_t` argument.

On MSVC 15.0 `sizeof(long long)` is 8 and `sizeof(size_t)` is 4. Smaller values fail because the number is correct but there is not enough memory. Larger values appear to pass because the number is truncated and the supposed memory is allocated, but when you index your imagined memory, it is out of range of the actual memory.

With MSVC, the default memory allowed is about 1.9 GB that includes everything, whether static or dynamic.

Comment: Shouldn't MSVC give a warning in this case as `long long` of `TAILLE_MAX` of 64 bit is truncated to 32 bits?

Comment: You can't `malloc` more than ~4GiBin Windows? Even on Win64??

Comment: @Paul Ogilvie indeed it does, *"warning C4244: 'function': conversion from '__int64' to 'size_t', possible loss of data"*.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: Not sure about MSVC, but there is no requirement in the standard, because conversion signed to unsigned is well defined. For gcc you should use `-Wconversion`.

Comment: @Olaf the *total* memory that can be used by the default compiler is about 1.9 Gb. So if 1 Gb of static data was used, only 0.9 can be obtained from `malloc`.

Comment: @WeatherVane: I do undestand this for Win32, but I wonder about Win64. So out of curiosity: how does one allocate more than this amount in Win64? Is this possible at all?

Comment: @Olaf I believe win 64 does have options but I not explored them, I mentioned the default. Of course you would need a 64-bit compiler.

Comment: sizeof(long long) returns 8

Comment: i think the problem is that `malloc` doesn't allocate the required size (anyway it can't) but it doesn't return an error, shouldn't it return NULL in place of allocating a different amount of memory ? !

Comment: No, because `malloc` had no idea that there was a truncation from 64 bits to 32. Suppose you wanted `0x140000000` bytes, which was passed as `0x40000000` bytes, do you see the problem? That was a valid allocation, but not what you wanted. Please have a look at `sizeof(size_t)` (the argument for `malloc`) too.

Comment: @youzking: Enable warnings and follow the rules of the language. Don't just use some type you want, but the correct types!

Comment: @WeatherVane yes that's it, the parameter's value is truncated, it is  about the max value that `size_t` can hold, knowing this i will take attention next time (y), thank you.

Comment: @Olaf , it seems that there is no warning cause the value of the parameter passed to `malloc` is calculated at the moment of the execution.

Comment: @youzking thank you, but didn't you get *"warning C4244: 'function': conversion from '__int64' to 'size_t', possible loss of data"* or similar? If not, please enable all compiler warnings.

Comment: @youzking: That would not prevent the compiler from detecting a type with higher rank is passed to a type with smaller rank. That's exactly what it should warn for. DId you try the option at all??

Comment: @WeatherVane @Olaf : i think i enabled all kind of warnings, this is the command :
`mingw32-gcc.exe -Wall -g -Wextra -Wall -std=c99  -c "code_file.c" -o "output.o"`

output :
`Process terminated with status 0 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))`
`0 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))`

Comment: @youzking You have not made explicit reply to various comments asking what is `sizeof (size_t)`.

Comment: You did not. Read my comments **carefully** again! (I don't post comments just to have them not be read)

Comment: @youzking Your options are the **minimum** recommendation. I typically have a lot of additional warnings enabled. You could try `-Wall`, but that might be too much. Better go through the gcc documentation and pick all reasonable warnings. If you don't understand the description, add it and see. If you don't get a messasge from the option, leave it enabled, otherwise think carefully if it is reasonable; if in doubt, search the web , possibly ask here if you still don't understand.

Comment: @Olaf about reading your comment i think you asked me if i tried the option and i showed my command.
@WeatherVane sorry, `sizeof(size_t)` gives 4.
@Olaf which command is used for truncation warnings ?

Comment: @Olaf MSVC does have that warning, as I have already commented. **youzking** that `sizeof(size_t)` giving 4 supports my answer, thanks for the vote.

Comment: @WeatherVane exactly it does, you're welcome.
in fact `-Wconversion` shows warnings about converting `size_t` from `long long int`, thank you @Olaf.

Answer (score 1):

It is operating system and computer specific. On Linux, it is called [*memory overcommitment*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_overcommitment) (a misfeature which makes the system always succeed on `malloc` or `mmap`  requests, even with an obscene size) and I generally disable it.

However, a bit of common sense should have alarmed you. You are requiring 5*10<sup>12</sup> words of 64 bits i.e. 8 bytes. That would mean 40*10<sup>12</sup> bytes. A gigabyte is 10<sup>9</sup> bytes (a bit more, if you want a power of two), and your laptop probably has only a few of them (likely at most 16GBytes in end of 2016). You are requesting 40 terabytes (that is 40000 gigabytes) of RAM (more precisely of [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space), backed up by RAM): even very expensive computers (e.g. costing a million € or US$) don't have that much RAM (addressable by a single core), and simply zeroing that much memory could take hours of CPU time.

In practice, you'll better allocate memory and grow it (using `realloc`) when needed. So code instead:

```
size_t size = 1000;
long long *T = malloc(size*sizeof(long long));
if (!T) { perror("malloc"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

<sup>(you always check against failure of `malloc`)</sup>

at some later point (e.g. when *reading the array*), you might feel necessary to grow the array; a general advice is to (heuristically) grow the size geometrically:

```
size_t newsize = 4*size/3 + 10;
T = realloc(T, newsize*sizeof(long long));
if (!T) { perror("realloc"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

Comment: very helpful thanks,  but i didn't understand why malloc didn't return NULL instead of allocating another size !

Comment: It is a [mis]feature of some operating systems.

Comment: thank you (y), the two responses was useful